# Why do I get an Error: unexpected token 'else' on line 26?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I started to create a website that doesn't solve quadratic equations yet, all it does is determines how many answers the equation will have based on the discriminant (b²-4ac). If it is greater than zero, then there are 2 solutions. If it is equal to zero then there is one solution. If it is less than zero, then there are no real solutions. In the console window, it shows an error on line 26, saying that there is an unexpected token 'else'. I have used if/else before and I have never come across this error. Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Quadratic Solver </title>
    <style></style>
    <script>
        function getDiscriminant() {
            var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
            var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
            var c = document.getElementById('c').value;
            var discriminant = (Math.pow(b, 2)) - (4 * a * c); // Basically getting the value of b²-4ac 

            if (discriminant > 0) {
                document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = "There are 2 real solutions";
            }
            elseif(discriminant = 0) {
                document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = "There is one real solution";
            } 
            else {// WHY DOES AN ERROR COME ON THIS LINE?
                document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = "There are no real solutions";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Quadratic Solver </h1>
    <p> Enter value of a </p>
    <input type="number" id="a" />
    <p> Enter value of b </p>
    <input type="number" id="b" />
    <p> Enter value of c </p>
    <input type="number" id="c" />
    <button onclick="getDiscriminant()"> Go! </button>
    <span id="myspan"> </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: first change `elseif` to `else if`

Comment: second, where's the span `myspan` `:)`

Comment: @Ele There it is, just before the ending body tag.

Comment: @Teemu I'm blind! `:)`

Comment: Because the line `elseif (discriminant=0)` is interpreted as a function call at the parsing time, and the following `else` is met without its leading `if` statement. Some browsers are giving "else without if" error, which might be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Its important to use

```
else if(){}
```

In Javascript You need a space beteeen else and if.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thing like elseif in javascript.
Use else if instead,
If you are a beginner, I recommend to you https://www.w3schools.com 
It has some great and symplistic explanations for most of web development.